# Set style based on variable?

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a control that wants to adjust its style based on a variable within its datacontext. As is I have a ListBox holding a list of contacts who are either customer or vendor.

Each contact has a name and is set to customer or vendor. Each customer has a recent purchase and an email whereas each vendor has a company name, fax, and sales info. So basically I'd like to have two separate styles based on the contact_type variable.

How could I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `ItemTemplateSelector` on your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) is designed to do

And really the template should be based on the class - not a variable
If the customer and vendor have some common properties then have them each implement the common interface

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass your `Contact` class into `Customer` and `Vendor` types, then you can simply define a different `DataTemplate` for each type, and WPF will automatically use the correct one. They can be included as resources of the `ListBox` as in the sample below, or higher up in the tree.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="...">
    <ListBox.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Customer}">
           ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Vendor}">
           ...
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```